# Angular2 - Populating a combobox/dropdown list

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a component called week-selector. The purpose of this component is to allow the user to choose a week that they wish to work with/view.

I am new to angular and understand the logic, however I am having trouble populating that dropdown list with some options. The following code displays on a page with no options within the boxes.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';
import{EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';

export class DropdownValue {
value:string;
label:string;

constructor(value:string,label:string) {
this.value = value;
this.label = label;
 }
}

@Component({
selector: 'app-week-selector',
template:
`
<form class = "ui small form segment">
<div id="WeekSubmission">
<h1> Please enter the week you are in: </h1>

<select>
<option> *ngFor="value of values" (click)="selectItem(value.value)">    {{value.label}}"> 
{{value}}
</option>
</select>

</div>
</form>
`
})

export class WeekSelectorComponent implements OnInit {
values:DropdownValue[];

@Output()
select:EventEmitter<string>;

constructor() {
this.values = [ new DropdownValue('Team','Liverpool')];
this.select = new EventEmitter();
}

selectItem(value){
 this.select.emit(value)
}

ngOnInit() {
 }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

For one-way binding use this as you would like to monitor the selection changes instead of just click: 
I assume you would like to show `value.label` in UI and record the same as value. You can change this value as per your requirement.

```
<select (change)="selectItem($event.target.value)">
    <option *ngFor="let value of values" value={{value.label}}>{{value.label}}</option>
</select>

// code
selectItem(value){
 this.select.emit(value)
}
```

For two-way data binding, you can use this:

```
<select [ngModel]="selectedValue" (ngModelChange)="selectItem($event)">
    <option [value]="value.label" *ngFor="let value of values">{{value.label}}</option>
</select>
```

To read in detail about data binding types in Angular, [consider reading my post about this topic](http://www.siddharthpandey.net/learn-data-binding-types-in-angular-with-examples/).

Comment: Don't you mean value={{value.value}}> ?

Answer (score 2):

If your code is exact copy paste, consider removing extra `>` in the HTML template for `option` tag.

IMHO it should be:

```
<option *ngFor="value of values" (click)="selectItem(value.value)">
{{value.label}}
</option>
```